Maximum network flow with few non-integral edges
Consider the following network:

$s\to a, s\to b$ with capacity $1.5$ each;
$a\to 1, a\to 2, a\to 3, b\to 1, b\to 2, b\to 3$ with infinite capacity each;
$1\to t, 2\to t, 3\to t$ with capacity $1$ each.

The maximum flow in this network is 3, and it saturates all edges from $s$ and to $t$. But for the infinite-capacity edges there are many options, for example:

Send $0.5$ through each of the 6 edges;
Send $1$ through $a\to 1$ and $b\to 3$, and $0.5$ through $a\to 2$ and $b\to 2$.

In my application, the second flow is better as it has fewer fractional edges.
Is there a polynomial-time algorithm that finds a maximum flow with the smallest number of fractional edges?

EDIT: Here is another example network:

$s\to a, s\to b$ with capacity $1.5$ each;
$a\to 1, a\to 2, a\to 3, b\to 2, b\to 3, b\to 4$ with infinite capacity each;
$1\to t, 2\to t, 3\to t, 4\to t$ with capacity $1$ each.

The maximum flow is $3$, where the two edges from $s$ are saturated. Suppose we start by running Ford-Fulkerson on the capacities rounded down. This can give us the path a flow of 1 through $s\to a \to 1 \to t$ and a flow of 1 through $s\to b \to 4\to t$.
Now, there are two options for augmenting paths on the remaining network:

$0.5$ through $s\to a\to 2\to t$ and $0.5$ through $s\to b\to 3\to t$ - here there are 4 fractional edges;
$0.5$ through $s\to a\to 2\to t$ and $0.5$ through $s\to b\to 2\to t$ - here there are only 2 fractional edges. The desired algorithm should pick this option and not the previous one.


One natural algorithm might be Ford-Fulkerson restricted to integer-capacity paths, repeated until you can find no further integer augmenting path; then Ford-Fulkerson with arbitrary-capacity paths, but using BFS to find the shortest augmenting path in each iteration, repeated until convergence.  Do you have an example of a network where this algorithm gives an incorrect solution?

@D.W. is the first step equivalent to just rounding down all capacities to the nearest integer, and finding a maximum flow on the rounded network?

Yes I think so (finding a maximum integral flow).

@D.W. See the example I added: if I understand your algorithm correctly, it may return incorrect results.

I think your problem is NP-hard here is why: 
Given an instance of the Subset-Sum problem $I = (<a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n>, S)$, you can construct a network-flow graph where you have three vertices a source $s$, a sink $t$ and another intermediate vertex $v$. For each element $a_i$ of the input array, you add one edge from $s$ to $v$ with integral capacity $a_i$. There will be $n$ such edges. Now put another edge of capacity $S$ from $v$ to $t$. Now you solve your special flow problem (let us call this $P$) on this constructed graph. The Subset-Sum instance $I$ is a 'yes' instance only if the flow solution results into all integral flows. [Necessary but not sufficient]
Disclaimer: The above reduction is only valid for one direction ('only if' case). For the other direction ('if' case) should be possible but in my opinion but I still haven't figured it out. I am posting this partially correct answer with the hope that other community members can dissect and comment on this. My intution is to scale all edges by some small $\epsilon$ (a fractional value) so that solution to your flow problem only selects those edges that actually constructs gives the required subset-sum $S$ (scaled by same $\epsilon$).

The problem is that you can have an integral flow, but not to the full capacity. For example, if an edge has capacity 10, then the flow through it could be 8. Thus the flow is integral, but does not correspond to a valid solution to Subset Sum.

Yes, you are right. That is why I said that the above reduction works well for only "no" instances. But maybe we can somehow make the capacities a fraction, and then possibly the "yes" instances also works. Again, I hope, someone more experienced can come up with a better proof or polytime algo.
